# Itext 7 alternative for itext 5 table.deleteBodyRows()

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I had to work on the project that used Itext 5, I am working on migrating it to Itext 7.

In Itext 5 they use `table.deleteBodyRows()` to clean the entire table body after writing it to the document and again manipulate the same table.

But Itext 7 there is no `deleteBodyRows()` method associated with Table. is there any alternative method for delete entire table body or otherwise what is the best way to handle this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Migrating from itext 5 to itext 7 in general is not a job of replacing each individual instruction by a pendant but one of rewriting whole blocks because the api changed considerably. Thus, you should probably look for a larger scale replacement. E.g. is there something hindering you to create a new table instance each time instead of clearing the old one?

Comment: @mkl that will be working solution but then all the table structuring and setup should do again and again. That's why I am seeking more iText specific way to clear table instead of initiate new table each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after some research, I was unable to find the proper iText specific answer for this question.

So, as @mkl mentioned we can re-initiate/ create a new table each time we write the data to the document. Just create a separate method to create a table with necessary structures and styles will reduce the workload you have to do when you create tables again and again.